# Convert text into date and time

Tags: powerquery

I have a table contains columns with date and time , I  am using power query to substract , but they are text , I  need to convert them to date and time so I  can substract
28/03/2023 02:00 AM   example of format

DateTime.FromText  give error
changing format to date time give error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
= DateTime.FromText([Date], [Culture="en-GB"])
```

[image]